# How to fetch feeds posted on my wall by a friend using Facebook graph aPI?

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

What's the best way to fetch feeds posted on my wall by a friend? I am using Facebook graph API for PHP?

I am using this REST call for fetching all feeds posted by a friend:

```
https://graph.facebook.com/friends_profile_id/feed?access_token=user_access_token
```

But I want to fetch only those feeds that are posted on my wall. Can anyone help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case you should be accessing your own wall at the `/me/feed` connection and filtering out those posts which were made by you, or you can grab it from the FQL stream table

For the FQL example, see the documentation at https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/stream/

A sample query (which will need an access token with read_stream access):

```
SELECT post_id, actor_id, target_id, message FROM stream WHERE source_id = me()
and actor_id != me() limit 50
```

Which returns the last 50 posts made on a user's wall, but not including posts they made themselves